# How can I get an effect to fade out before another fades in, with an "if/else" statement in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I have been trying different things for a while now, but I'm still unable to get one DIV to fade out, and have another one fade in.  I have searched the site, but I'm still new to jQuery, so I don't understand certain syntax and whatnot.

If someone could explain the easiest way to have my code check to see if a DIV is already in-view (probably with an if statement)--if not, having the DIV selected by the user fade in.  If one is already in view, have it fade that DIV out, and fade in the newly selected one.

Thanks, again!

Comment: What have you  tried?

Comment: What do you mean by in-view? are you talking about visibility or scrolling..? hope the answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a callback for the fadeIn and fadeOut functions in jQuery, you just need to add the code inside that callback:

```
$( "#willDisappear" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // #willDisappear is Hidden.

    $( "#willAppear" ).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Or the other way:

```
$( "#willAppear" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // #willAppear is Visible now.

    $( "#willDisappear" ).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Javascript uses events, callbacks are just functions you pass to, in this case fadeIn, to use whenever an event is triggered, in this case when fadeIn is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you can use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector to check the visibility of an element to hide it using [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) and show the other element using [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) in the callback of [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) function.

```
$('input').click(function(){
  if($('#first').is(':visible'))
    $('#first').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('#second').fadeIn('slow');
    });
 else
    $('#second').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('#first').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QBw5p/)